# save a large cell matrix (string variables) in Matlab is very slow and size is massive

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a big cell matrix (string variables) with 40,000,000 lines. I first check the size using whos('file'), and it tells me that the size of the matrix in the workspace is 4.5GB. Then, I use 'save('file',-v7.3) in order to export it to .mat file. It takes so long time and after 10 mins is still saving, so I check the file in the target directory, the file size is already 12GB and is still increasing. Can anybody tell me what happen? Is there any other way to save this matrix? It doesn't need to be a .mat file, it can be .txt or something else.

A small part of the matrix.
'00086810'
'00192610'
'00213T10'
'00339010'
'00350L10'
'00350P10'
'00428010'
'00431F10'
'00433710'
'00723110'
'00743710'
'00818210'
'00818810'
'01031710'
'01204610'
'01747610'
'01747F10'
'01852Q10'
'01853510'
'01887110'
'01888510'
'01890A10'
'01920510'
'02316010'
'02343R10'
'02361310'
'02391210'
'02407310'
'02407640'
'02408H10'
'02434310'
'02520W10'
'02581610'

Comment: I dont know about your fie sizes, but I am sure it will take time. It takes me 10 minutes to move 4GB from one place to another in my hard drive.If you want faster buy a SSD

Comment: are there other variables in the workspace when you ran `save('file',-v7.3)`? because that will save them all in a matfile named file, try `save('file','file','-v7.3')`... (the first input is the file name)

Comment: Are all cells in it `8 char` long?

Comment: Re Ander: the matrix is named st_nonfin in the workspace. So I just write this 'save('st_nonfin','-v7.3')'. It is still saving, 30GB now!!

Comment: Re Divakar:  some of the variables are less than 8 char

Comment: the first input is the filename for the file created... that would still save **all** variables in the workspace `save('filename','st_nonfin','-v7.3')` would ensure **only** the `st_nofin` variable is saved. (I'm still working on the assumption that the problem is to do with having other large variables in the workspace)

Comment: Re RTL :  use your version still overhead

Answer (score 0):

Lets test

```
test='helloooooo'
whos('test')

  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  test      1x10               20  char    

save('A','test')
size  A file 184 bytes
```

Lets test bigger data.

```
 symbols = ['a':'z' 'A':'Z' '0':'9'];
 MAX_ST_LENGTH = 500;
 stLength = randi(MAX_ST_LENGTH);

 for ii=1:100
    nums = randi(numel(symbols),[1 stLength]);
    testcell{ii} = symbols (nums);

 end
    save('test','testcell')

     whos('testcell')




Name          Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

  testcell      1x100            52200  cell
```

Size file 15.7Kb

It compresses data. BUT I realised that it depends in the data. however usually I got x3 compression

Can you show us you code, maybe you are saving things wrongly

Comment: Could you show the increase from a cell array with 2 strings to a cell array with 3 strings? Now we may just be looking at startup overhead.